# When clicking on kendo grid cell and tabbing, grid loses focus

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid where I am able to tab through and edit without having to use the navigatable property in my kendo grid.

Everything works fine when tabbing through cells that are set to editable as true in the schema, but when I randomly click a cell that is not editable and click tab then the grid loses focus and tabs around the browser, which is not what I want. I need to be able to tab from that uneditable cell and still keep on going on my merry way of tabbing through the cells.

I do not want to use the navigatable property.

```js
var g_EditCellObject = [];

function CreateGrid() {

  let fieldName, whichTable, grid, item, dataItem, selectedItem, record, cols, currentCell, dataLength, data,
    currentCellIndex, foundPromptAnswer, cellColumn, rowIndex, tr, me, itemGrid, innrHTML, foundMissingAnswer, foundRow, itemPrompts;

  $("#EntryGrid").empty();
  $("#EntryGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: addBlankRows([]),
      schema: {
        model: {
          id: "CatalogID",
          fields: {
            CatalogName: {
              type: "string",
              editable: true,
              hidden: false
            },
            CatalogVersion: {
              type: "string",
              editable: false,
              hidden: false
            },
            CatalogActive: {
              type: "number",
              editable: true,
              hidden: false
            },
            CatalogStartPrice: {
              type: "string",
              editable: true,
              hidden: false
            },
            CatalogMiddlePrice: {
              type: "string",
              editable: true,
              hidden: false
            },
            CatalogEndPrice: {
              type: "string",
              editable: true,
              hidden: false
            },
            CatalogQty: {
              type: "number",
              editable: true,
              hidden: false
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    columns: [
      //{ field: "CatalogID", title: "CatalogID", locked: true, width: "50px", hidden: true, editable: false },
      {
        field: "CatalogName",
        title: "Name",
        locked: true,
        width: "200px",
        hidden: false,
        attributes: {
          class: "editable-cell column-locked"
        },
        editor: CatalogDropDownEditor
      },
      {
        field: "CatalogVersion",
        title: "Version",
        locked: true,
        width: "200px",
        hidden: false
      },
      {
        field: "CatalogActive",
        title: "Active",
        locked: true,
        width: "200px",
        hidden: false,
        attributes: {
          class: "editable-cell column-locked"
        }
      },
      {
        field: "CatalogStartPrice",
        title: "Start Price",
        width: "200px",
        hidden: false,
        attributes: {
          class: "editable-cell column-locked"
        }
      },
      {
        field: "CatalogMiddlePrice",
        title: "Middle Price",
        width: "200px",
        hidden: false,
        attributes: {
          class: "editable-cell column-locked"
        }
      },
      {
        field: "CatalogEndPrice",
        title: "End Price",
        width: "200px",
        hidden: false,
        attributes: {
          class: "editable-cell column-locked"
        }
      },
      {
        field: "CatalogQty",
        title: "Qty",
        width: "200px",
        hidden: false,
        attributes: {
          class: "editable-cell column-locked"
        }
      }
    ],
    editable: {
      mode: "incell",
      confirmation: false
    },
    beforeEdit: function(e) {

    },
    edit: function(e) {
      e.sender.current(e.container[0]);

      whichTable = e.sender.current().closest("table").is(e.sender.lockedTable) ? "LockedTable" : "UnlockedTable";
      const fieldName = e.sender.editable.options.fields.field;

      g_EditCellObject = [];
      g_EditCellObject.push({
        originTable: whichTable,
        currentCellIndex: e.container.index(),
        currentRowIndex: e.container.parent().index()
      });

    },
    save: function(e) {

    },
    change: function(e) {

    },
    sortable: false,
    //navigatable: true,
    selectable: "row",
    reorderable: false,
    groupable: false,
    filterable: false,
    columnMenu: false,
    pageable: false,
    height: "500px"
  });
}

function addBlankRows(dataSource) {

  //#region Variable Declarations

  let minRowCount, persistentExtraEmptyRows, obj, dataSourceLen, totalBlankRows;

  minRowCount = 10;
  persistentExtraEmptyRows = 10;
  rowNumber = null;
  obj = getBlankItemRow(null);
  dataSourceLen = dataSource.length;
  totalBlankRows;

  //#endregion

  if (dataSourceLen < persistentExtraEmptyRows)
    totalBlankRows = minRowCount - dataSourceLen;
  else
    totalBlankRows = persistentExtraEmptyRows;

  for (let i = 1; i <= totalBlankRows + 6; i++) {
    dataSource.push(obj);
  }

  return dataSource;
}

function getBlankItemRow(itemKey) {
  return {
    CatalogID: 0,
    CatalogVersion: "",
    CatalogActive: "",
    CatalogStartPrice: "",
    CatalogMiddlePrice: "",
    CatalogEndPrice: "",
    CatalogQty: ""
  };
}

function onGridKeydown(e) {

  //#region Variable Declarations

  let grid, current, nextCell, prevRow, nextRow, lRowUid, landOnName, gridData, rowHolder, lastRow, lastRow2,
    row, col, selectedItem, currentCell;
  g_ArrivedByTab = true;

  //#endregion

  //SetSelectedGridRow("#EntryGrid", 0);
  grid = $("#EntryGrid").getKendoGrid();
  currentCell = grid.current();

  if (e.keyCode === kendo.keys.TAB) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const row = grid.select().index();
    const col = grid.cellIndex($(e.target).closest("td"));

    const lRowUid = grid.current().parent().next().data("uid");

    const nextRow = grid.tbody.find(`tr[data-uid="${lRowUid}"]`);


    const lockedColumnsLength = 3;
    const unLockedColumnsLength = 4;
    const nextCellIndex = g_EditCellObject[0].currentCellIndex + 1;

    if (nextRow.length === 0) {
      nextCell = grid.tbody.find("tr:eq(0) td:eq(0)");

      if (nextCellIndex === unLockedColumnsLength) {
        const landOnName = grid.tbody.find("tr:eq(0) td:eq(0)");

        grid.editCell($(landOnName[0]));

        grid.current($(landOnName[0]));
      } else {
        nextCell = grid.tbody.find("tr:eq(" + g_EditCellObject[0].currentRowIndex + ") td:eq(" + nextCellIndex + ")");
        grid.current(nextCell);
        grid.editCell(nextCell);
      }
    } else {
      if (g_EditCellObject[0].originTable === "LockedTable") {
        nextCell = grid.tbody.find("tr:eq(" + g_EditCellObject[0].currentRowIndex + ") td:eq(" + nextCellIndex + ")");
        grid.current(nextCell);
        grid.editCell(nextCell);
        if (nextCellIndex === unLockedColumnsLength) {
          const landOnName = nextRow.find("td:eq(0)");

          grid.editCell($(landOnName[0]));

          grid.current($(landOnName[0]));
        }
      } else {
        nextCell = grid.tbody.find("tr:eq(" + g_EditCellObject[0].currentRowIndex + ") td:eq(" + nextCellIndex + ")");
        grid.current(nextCell);
        grid.editCell(nextCell);
        if (nextCellIndex === unLockedColumnsLength) {
          const landOnName = nextRow.find("td:eq(0)");

          grid.editCell($(landOnName[0]));

          grid.current($(landOnName[0]));
        }
      }
    }

  }
}

$(document).ready(() => {
  CreateGrid();
  $("#EntryGrid").find("table").on("keydown", onGridKeydown);
});

function GetData(whichData) {
  const CatalogData = [{
      CatalogID: 1,
      CatalogName: "Abes"
    },
    {
      CatalogID: 2,
      CatalogName: "Bobs"
    },
    {
      CatalogID: 3,
      CatalogName: "Coles"
    },
    {
      CatalogID: 4,
      CatalogName: "Dans"
    }
  ];

  //const 

  //return whichData;
  return CatalogData;
}

var g_DataSource = [];

function ReturnData(model) {
  const itemModel = {
    CatalogID: model.CatalogID,
    CatalogName: model.CatalogName,
    CatalogVersion: model.CatalogVersion,
    CatalogActive: model.CatalogActive,
    CatalogStartPrice: model.CatalogStartPrice,
    CatalogMiddlePrice: model.CatalogMiddlePrice,
    CatalogEndPrice: model.CatalogEndPrice,
    CatalogQty: model.CatalogQty
  };

  return itemModel;
}

function CreateDataItem() {
  g_DataSource.push();
}

function CatalogDropDownEditor(container, options) {

  //#region Variable Declarations

  let grid, selectedItem, me, selectedArea, prevArea;
  grid = $('#EntryGrid').getKendoGrid();
  selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());

  //#endregion


  const catalogs = GetData(null);
  $(`<input data-text-field="CatalogName" data-value-field="CatalogName" data-bind="value:${options.field}"/>`)
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoDropDownList({
      dataTextField: "CatalogName",
      dataValueField: "CatalogID",
      dataSource: {
        data: catalogs
      },
      change: function(e) {

        const dataItem = $("#EntryGrid").getKendoGrid().dataItem("tr:eq(" + g_EditCellObject[0].currentRowIndex + ")");
        const name = e.sender.dataItem().CatalogName;
        dataItem.set("CatalogName", name);
      },
      select: function(e) {

      },
      close: function(e) {

      }
    });
}
```

```css
#EntryGrid tr {
  height: 31px !important;
}

input {
  height: 26px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div id="EntryGrid"></div>
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use navigatable? Does it clash with another feature you're using? (Also could you remove all the `hidden:false` from your example?)